# Form data not being posted to $.ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

When posting my form from a custom CSS modal the data is being posted to the current URL and not the set url.

```
$("form.delete_photo_form").submit(function(e) 
{
    e.preventDefault();

    $(".delete_photo_message").text("");


    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/php/delete_photo.php',
        type: 'post',
        data:  $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data, status) 
        {
            if (data == 1)
            {
                $(".delete_photo_message").text("Unable to delete photo");
            }                           
            else if (data == 2)
            {
                $(".delete_photo_message").text("Photo deleted");
                // checkGroup();
            }                           
            else
            {
                $(".delete_photo_message").text(data);  
            }
      },
      error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
      }
    });
```

This form is being posted from a modal opened by another modal.

Original modal:

```
<div id="photo_buttons">

<a id="edit_photo_modal" class="button" href="#edit_photos_modal">

    Edit Photos

</a>
<div id="edit_photos_modal" class="modal_photos">
    <div>
        <a id="close_edit_photo" title="Close" href="#close"></a>


                                Edit Photos:


        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <div class="edit_photos_div">
            <div class="photo_line">
                <img src="images/thumbnails/group/11/bb0878d2390cdcfb.jpg"></img>
                <br></br>
                <a id="edit_photo" class="open_modal" href="#modal_edit_photo_39">

                    Edit

                </a>


                                      /  


                <a id="delete_photo" href="#modal_delete_photo_39">

                    Delete

                </a>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
            </div>                
        </div>
        <a id="finish_edit" class="button" title="Finish" href="#finish">

            Finish

        </a>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/edit_photo.js"></script>
```

Second Modal (this one is where the ajax post is called):

```
    <div id="edit_modals">
    <div id="modal_edit_photo_39" class="modal">
        <div>
            <a id="close_39" title="Close" href="#close">

                Close

            </a>
            <form id="edit_photo_form_39" class="edit_photo_form" method="post" action="">
                <h4>

                    Edit Photo

                </h4>
                <br></br>
                <h3 id="edit_photo_message" class="edit_photo_message"></h3>



                                            Title:

                <input id="edit_title" type="text" value="Test photo" name="edit_title"></input>



                                            Description:

                <textarea id="edit_desc" name="edit_desc" rows="3">

                    Test for resize

                </textarea>
                <br></br>
                <input type="hidden" value="11" name="group_id"></input>
                <input type="hidden" value="39" name="photo_id"></input>
                <input id="edit_photo_yes_39" class="edit_yes" type="submit" title="Edit" value="Edit" name="edit_yes"></input>
                <a id="cancel_edit" class="button" title="Cancel" href="#cancel_edit">

                    Cancel

                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="modal_delete_photo_39" class="modal">
        <div>
            <a id="close_39" title="Close" href="#close">

                Close

            </a>
            <form id="delete_photo_form_39" class="delete_photo_form" method="post" action="">
                <h4>

                    Are you sure you want to delete this photo?

                </h4>
                <br></br>
                <h3 id="delete_photo_message" class="delete_photo_message"></h3>
                <input type="hidden" value="11" name="group_id"></input>
                <input type="hidden" value="39" name="photo_id"></input>
                <input id="delete_photo_yes_39" class="delete_yes" type="submit" title="Yes" value="Yes" name="delete_yes"></input>
                <a id="del_no" class="button" title="No" href="#no">

                    No

                </a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

If anybody has any ideas please let me know.

Side note:

The form submit function works fine if the second modal is called on its own and not from the first.

Comment: Leaving the form `action` blank means that it will post to the same page it exists on after running through your jQuery and ajax. I don't see another URL in your code aside from the location of your php script within your ajax, so I guess this begs the question, "What were you expecting to happen?"

Comment: e.preventDefault(); Should stop this from happening shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you're either dynamically creating the form *after* the `$("form.delete_photo_form")` selector has run, or the modal script could be moving the form's location in the DOM (i.e., some modal scripts move the modal content to the very end of the `<body>` tag).

In either case, this would cause your submit logic not to run.  Try replacing:

`$("form.delete_photo_form").submit(<handler>);`

...with:

`$(document).on("submit", "form.delete_photo_form", <handler>);`

If you're not familiar with the above syntax, it's jQuery's syntax for [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), which allows you to bind the event handler to something permanent (like the `document` object), and then selectively run handler logic if the event meets certain criteria (in this case, the event has to be of type "submit" and must have originated from within an element matching the `"form.delete_photo_form"` selector).  This has the advantage of letting you set up the event listener even if the relevant DOM nodes haven't been created yet.

Comment: While i have not used the $(document).on("submit", "form.delete_photo_form", <handler>); I have found that you are correct and the dynamic forms were being created after the selector. I have now changed the order of execution and the forms are working as desired. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you're not going to submit the form at all why don't use onclick function of your button and there in the method call the ajax.

Try to take every value and send all of them to check if they have something

Comment: This is how i would like to have done it but i am unsure on how to get the form data from a dynamically created form and button. The page will likely have many of the forms and buttons, hence why im using the form.class submit. I did look at getting the parent then all child data but was unsuccessful.

Comment: Maybe this is an error but why don't use

`$('form[class="delete_photo"]')` 

instead of 
`$('form.delete_photo')`

or simple $('#id')